# Can one conduct training an SVM with detected false positives iteratively?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm working on a machine learning problem in image processing. I want to get the location of an object in an image by using Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) and a support vector machine (SVM). I've read a couple of articles and tutorials about training the SVM. The setup is pretty standard. I have labeled positive training images and now need to generate a set of negative training samples.

In literature, the approach to generate negative training samples by randomly choosing a position is found very often. I've also seen some approaches where in a successive step to choosing random negative samples, the false-positives of a detection are used as negative training samples once again. 
However, I'm wondering if one could not use this approach generally from the start. So one would generate only one false training sample randomly, run the detection and put false-positives in the negative training set again. This seems quite an obvious strategy to me, but I wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: Just a hunch (I know some things about ML, but never did image processing): if you start with a single negative training sample, you get a very bad classifier, so you'll need more iterations of the train-detect FN-expand training set-repeat loop.

Comment: i guess it really might speed things up to start with more than one negative sample. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory behind this method is laid out in [Object Detection with Discriminatively Trained Part Based Models](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~pff/papers/lsvm-pami.pdf) by P. Felzenszwalb, R. Girshick, D. McAllester, D. Ramanan in their PAMI paper. In essence, your starting negative set does not matter, you will always converge to the same classifier if you iteratively add hard samples (with an SVM margin > -1). Starting with a single negative would simply make this convergence slower.

Answer (score 3):

To me it sounds like you want to train the SVM classifier online/incrementally, i.e. updating the classifier with new samples. Such methods are generally only used if new data comes available over time. In your case it seems that you can generate a whole set of negative training samples, so there would be no need to train it incrementally. I'm inclined to say that training the classifier in one run will be better than doing this incrementally (as hinted at by larsmans).

Comment: thanks for the hint for online/incremental classifier updates. you are exactly right, for my use-case I do not need to update a classifier incrementally. However I was wondering if using false-positives rather than randomly sampled negative samples might lead to better classification results.

Comment: Such techniques exists indeed and are called `Boosting`, with [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) being a popular algorithm. They often assume a `weak learner` as classifier (which is a classifier that classifies the data only slightly better than random). Several weak learners are trained consecutively focussing on the samples which were wrongly classified by the previously learners.

Comment: thanks for the link to AdaBoost. I've heard of it but never actually used it in a project before. As you've pointed out I've seen some applications using it to combine multiple weak classifiers into a stronger one. But I can't see the link from AdaBoost to selecting good negative samples for a SVM. Is your comment about using AdaBoost as a replacement for an SVM in this application?

Comment: AdaBoost is a meta-algorithm, which uses a normal classification algorithm 'internally'. So you could implement AdaBoost with SVM as its 'internal' classification algorithm. The thing with AdaBoost is that it assumes weak learners while SVM is a 'strong' learner. There are [studies](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=adaboost+scm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs#hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=0wH&channel=fs&sa=X&ei=L1MZUO74GMOnhAecjIDQCQ&ved=0CE4QBSgA&q=adaboost+svm&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=f3e1a7fc45514a46&biw=1920&bih=908) though which try to combine them.

Comment: Boosting is not directly related to the problem at hand, though.

Comment: As background, you basically cannot do it in one run. If you're e.g. looking for cars in an image, there are few bounding boxes that actually outline a car, and orders of magnitude more bounding boxes that don't (wrong position, scale, ...). That's why you're doing it incrementally.

Comment: @etarion exactly. if one plans to add found false-positives after one classification run. you need to do it incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

(Again, I'm not an image processing specialist, so take this with a grain of salt.)

> I'm wondering if one could not use this approach generally from the start.

You'd need some way to detect the false positives from a classification run. To do so, you need a ground truth, that is, you need a human in the loop. In effect, you'd be doing [active learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_%28machine_learning%29). If that's what you want to do, you could just as well start with a bunch of hand-labeled negative examples.

Alternatively, you could set this up as a [PU learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PU_learning) problem. I have no idea whether that works well with images, but for text classification, it sometimes works.